# Is Oracle Rules Manager and Expression Filter based on an existing standard?

Tags: oracle, rule-engine

If not, are there standards in existence for rules engine storage?

or

Is there a C# implementation of the Oracle Rules Engine syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

I only have a little experience with Rules Manager and Expression Filter, and it's difficult to say if something is not based on a standard, but here's my reasoning:

- Oracle seems to love talking about standards in their documentation.  For example, there are many standards mentioned in the [SQL Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm) but there are none mentioned in the [Rules Manager and Expression Filter guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14288/toc.htm).
- As @Adam Hawkes mentioned, Oracle Business Rules Engine uses various standards, like JSR-94, and also the Rete algorithm.  (But I'm in no position to judge how well they follow those standards.)  However, Oracle Business Rules Engine and Rules Manager/Expression Filter are completely unrelated products.  (Even though they're made by the same company and do almost the same thing.)
- If there was a standard, someone on here would know about it and would have answered by now.

For similar reasons I'm also guessing the answer is No to the other questions.

Comment: accepted as correct for the effort. Both current answers upvoted since both contributed.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle Business Rules Engine is supposedly an implementation of the Java "JSR 94" API. Not sure that there is a standard for the "storage" of the rules, but there is a standard for expressing/using the rules.